# Install 32- or 64-bit Crystal Reports runtime on 64-bit server?

Tags: installation, crystalreports

To run, our VB.NET application needs the runtime files Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio. (Support Pack SP8)

We are installing our application on Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit.

The target CPU of our VB.NET app is x86.

Do we install the 32bit MSI or the 64 bit runtime?

*[For the list of Crystal Report installation files, see [http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824]](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know. Is your application 32 bit or 64 bit? You can set this up for VB.NET.... and.... 64 bit makes maybe little sense for most apps (that is the reason there is no 64 bit office in wide use - ms recommends against the use of it unless there is a need, like HUUUUUGH excel sheets).

As you say:

> The target CPU of our VB.NET app is x86.

That says you hav a 32 bit application. So you need the 32 bit runtime.